# dimmensions of a decora insert

Tags: electrical, switch

I am designing a temp sensor that I want to insert in a decora panel.

I have googled this and cannot find anything from leviton and cannot tell if the size measurements on blank inserts include the mount tabs as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever think to purchase a couple of Decora covers and one or two Decora style switches or outlets from the harware store or from the big box home center. You could then just simply measure them!!

Comment: I have no access to a hardware store currently as I am in college and do not have a car.

Comment: Amazon? (7 chr)

Comment: What part of I'm a college student did you not understand. I am basically broke and in any case did not want to buy anything in the first place.

Comment: I am sorry if I implied that you should be buying anything. But afterall you did say that you want to insert your temp sensor in an Decora panel. At some time it seems very reasonable to take steps to "try out the fit of your device" before you commit the whole semesters work. A panel in hand would be a key strategy toward a successful demonstration of your project.

Comment: Yes. I see your point and I am sorry that I went off on you. The project is personal so there is no need right now to prototype and I was just looking for dimensions so I could start designing the panel in cad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device 6.66 x 3.30 cm

Hole in trim plate 6.68 x 3.32 cm

2 mm ( 0.20 cm) radius on the corners.

Comment: These numbers imply that there is only 0.1mm gap between the device and the trim plate... looking at the Decora devices around my house it looks like it's a lot more than that—maybe 1mm. Any thoughts?

Comment: there is probably some manufacturing tolerances involved.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, after just a little more googling i found [this](http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/ibcGetAttachment.jsp?cItemId=cV3Xai4kP3lLQtSp99zhdw&label=IBE&appName=IBE&LEVCOMP_pses=ZG661BE71730E060E08B11C24F0EF8E8FD7E435240AF69C639D52CE28C36FF45276572CF6746CC27E5861BA32458603230305FF0216919AA5B&minisite=10251) link which I hope does not break which lists the dimensions as 1.29 inches wide x 0.22 inches thick x 2.61 inches tall without mounting tabs and 3.81 inches tall with tabs.